# Problems using WNetGetConnection

Tags: c, winapi, networking

According to Microsoft this function should *retrieve the name of the network resource associated with a local device*.

I am using an adaptation of the code on [this Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), compiling in C.  But even though the drives ("J:", and "X:") are mapped on my PC,  this function does not return the share for either of them.  Rather it results in either ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED or ERROR_CONNECTION_UNAVAIL.

***Note:*** As a double check, to eliminate the possibility that I was bumping up against UAC, or some other access problem, I called *WNetGetConnection(,,)* from within MS Excel using a macro with code **[from this site](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/ap200001.asp)**.  *It worked just fine*.

My exact C code implementation is below.

Any ideas?

My adaptation using ANSI C, built and run on Windows 7, (must include mpr.lib)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ansi_c.h>

LPTSTR szDeviceName[260]; //MAX_PATHNAME_LEN
DWORD dwResult, cchBuff = sizeof(szDeviceName); 

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Call the WNetGetConnection function.
    dwResult = WNetGetConnection(argv[1], 
        (LPTSTR) szDeviceName, 
        &cchBuff); 

    switch (dwResult) 
    { 
        //
        // Print the connection name or process errors.
        //
        case NO_ERROR: 
            printf("Connection name: %s\n", szDeviceName); 
            break; 
        //
        // The device is not a redirected device.
        //
        case ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED: 
            printf("Device %s is not connected.\n", argv[1]); 
            break;
        //
        // The device is not currently connected, but it is a persistent connection.
        //
        case ERROR_CONNECTION_UNAVAIL: 
            printf("Connection to %s is unavailable.\n", argv[1]); 
            break;
        //
        // Handle the error.
        //
        default: 
            printf("WNetGetConnection failed.\n"); 
    }
    getchar();

}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce on Windows 7 box. Who mapped the network drvie?

Comment: @StatusBreakPoint - It does not seem to matter who created the mapping, IT or me.  Same results

Comment: It sort of smells like an ANSI vs. UNICODE issue.  Can you build it explicitly for UNICODE and see if it reproduces?

Comment: @EricBrown - I actually ftp'ed the entire project directory to a PC on an isolated network (where we have different UAC and group policy settings), also running Windows 7.  I built and ran it there with the correct results.  So I am now thinking Group Policy or UAC have something to do with this behavior.  I will look at what I need to do for UNICODE.  The original code required some modifications to build in my environment (LabWindows/CVI) which is ANSI.  If I see improvement after doing this, I will post it here.

Comment: @StatusBreakPoint - If you are still following this, would you mind trying something.  Right click the exe you build, and run it as admin to see if the results are any different than running it un-elevated.

Comment: @ryyker - If application is running in the same session as the mapping session and you get these errors, I have no idea. I am sorry.